# How to stick oreo biscuits together to make a tower?

Tags: cookies, decorating

I am attempting a castle cake with a dragon on it. I also want to make a tower to stick and stand up on the castle. The general idea to create the tower is to stick Oreo biscuits together and then to fondant the outside to make it look like a stone wall tower.

Can someone please help me figure out how to stick the biscuits together? I tried to Google but couldn't find much.

Comment: Please don't create new tags for every question.

Comment: How are you attempting to stick them together?  Shingled?  Stacked (flat-to-flat)?  Edge-to-edge?  Each way would require a slightly different method.

Comment: @Joe: I wanted to have them stacked, so I could make them look like a tower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to experiment, if you want to use oreos.

The problem is that you need somethign strong enough to allow you to roll the glued together tower in fondant.

I would try, in order:

- Tempered chocolate, if you can do that; its pretty strong when fully cooled
- Royal icing
- Very thick ganache
- Peanut butter

Comment: @divi I suggest coming to chat to brainstorm.  See:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11994063#11994063 for some more thoughts

Comment: I really doubt whether you can really make anything approaching "tower"-height without reinforcement from a dowel or some such; problem is, Oreos don't have a hole in their middles.

Comment: Oreos are prettty strong.  It might be doable, at least with tempered chocolate, I think.  In both tension and compression.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: thanks for the ideas. I liked your suggestion of royal icing and tried that last night. I've left the biscuits to stand for a day in an airtight container. Will let you know the results tonight

Comment: Professionals use dowel or other materials to create such structures. This time of the year, you might be able to find nice, long and straight peppermint sticks that you could use instead of a dowel.  Take a drop of water and moisten the center of the biscuits to soften them up so you can drill out a hole.  Then stack them up on the peppermint stick with any of the "glues" suggested above.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: Royal Icing was great and the biscuits are glued together with no issues. Thanks

Comment: You might also try caramel, that's what's used to stick choux puffs together for a croquembouche.

Comment: @sourd'oh Yeah, one of my alternative structural ideas was caramel popcorn...

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend that unless you're just stacking oreos on top of each other, that you use something else for structure and then afix the oreos on using icing as a mastic.

Typically, you'd use one of the following:

- A hollow structure made of gingerbread sheets, fastened together
- A bit of dense cake (eg, pound cake), cut down to the proper size
- Rice crispie treats, formed into the size you wanted

Personally, I'd go with the rice crispie treats, in part because you can just use that without any oreos.  (you can either take a handle of a spoon or similar and press in the texture you want once it's mostly but not fully set).

... but you can also deal with the texturing on the fondant ... just roll the fondant out a bit thick, apply it, and then use something appropriately sized and smooth (no sharp edges) to press in the grout lines.  If you have clay working tools, use those, but also the back edge of some table knives will work.   You have a longer working time than trying to do this on rice crispie treats, you just have to be more careful about not tearing or cutting the fondant.

Comment: Thanks that's a great idea. I'll try this with rice crispie treats next time

Answer (score 1):

This type of fancy cakes usually has inedible internal supports, such as wood rods. I wouldn't trust the cookies to remain safely upright even after being glued. My intuition would pronounce a glued tower stable if its height is 2x diameter max, anything above feels problematic. It is a different case if you create a hard tower with the cookies somehow embedded in it, but this means we are talking something like embedding cookies in hard candy, which doesn't sound appetizing and probably looks strange. In the end, it will probably work better without cookies.

The alternative would be to create maybe a four corner "basket" out of rods to put the stack inside, and decorate the stocks nicely. In this case, you can use a fairly weak glue, even some whipped cream will be OK, because the glue doesn't have to support the structure.

There are videos on the Internet for creating fancy cakes, often episodes of reality TV shows. You might want to watch them for inspiration. I haven't seen any with a cookie tower, but I have seen 3-D models of stag heads and other sculptures, you can learn a lot from them.